# Ansible AWX container 17.0.1 date inside container not correct

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-20.04, ansible-awx

I've install AWX container version which contain 4 containers (awx_task, awx_web, awx_postgres, awx_redis) on ubuntu 20.04

here is the ansible version inside container awx_web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wITL0.png)

I've add the env to change timezone to all containers in docker-compose.yml

```
 environment
    TZ: Aaia/Bangkok
```

Once the containers are up so I've exec into them and checking with "date" command and the result is work as expect. The time is a Bangkok Timezone (+07)

So I've declare ansible global variable in one files (defaults.yml) and running basic playbook to print out the time from playbook if it is correct (these are execute inside container awx_web)

```
TIMESTAMP_BANGKOK: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') }}"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE5dR.png)

You can see the result above are correct

but when I run this playbook on AWX GUI the output of the same playbook are incorrect (it shown UTC +0 instead).

but the execute time at the right side is Bangkok time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/545Jm.png)

What could be wrong and where should I reconfigure? any suggestion is appreciated.

I've tried with setting the timezone but seem not helping

```
- name: Set timezone to Asia/Bangkok
  timezone:
    name: Asia/Bangkok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding TZ environment directly on command

Before

```
TIMESTAMP_BANGKOK: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') }}"
```

After

```
TIMESTAMP_BANGKOK: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'TZ=Asia/Bangkok date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') }}"
```

So I assume that declare Timezone in docker-compose or declare on the playbook pre_task doesn't help.